# How to get IPs of 8 peers my node propagates transactions and blocks to?

Tags: network

I see that `bitcoin-cli` can do `getpeerinfo`. However, it typically returns around 30 different IPs. Even if I ask for only outbound ones, I get around 16 addresses.

```
$ bitcoin-cli getpeerinfo | grep "inbound\": false" | wc -l
16
```

How do I narrow down to those 8 that will be used to propagate the next block my node gets to propagate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitcoin Core nodes propagate blocks and transactions to *all* their peers, not just outbound ones.

And if you have 16 peers that `getpeerinfo` reports `"inbound": false` for, then all 16 are outbound connections. Presumably you're using `addnode` functionality, or using modified source code, as Bitcoin Core itself will not make more than 10 automatic outbound connections, but for manual connections (addnode) there is a separate limit.